# How to migrate a database from MyISAM to InnoDB?

Tags: mysql, database, migration, database-administration

I am migrating a database with MyISAM tables to an InnoDB engine.

Some of the tables in MyISAM have full text indexes. If I have to retain the full text indexes in InnoDB engine, what are the things that I need to do?

I've read that versions of MySQL before 5.6 do not support full text indexing natively in InnoDB. I am using MySQL 5.5 in Amazon RDS.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it. If you need full text indexes, and you're on MySQL 5.5 or earlier, then you can't use the InnoDB storage engine. Either upgrade to 5.6.4 or later, index your text in some other way, or leave those tables as MyISAM.

Comment: can I use sphinx for full test indexing along with InnoDB Engine in MySQL 5.5 ?? The Problem is I am on Amazon RDS and I will not be able to install anything.  If I am running on a EC2 instance, will I be able to use  sphinx for full test indexing along with InnoDB Engine in MySQL 5.5 ?